Como crear una lista de diccionarios utilizando Input en python
producto = {}
lista_de_productos=[]
keys = ['Nombre', 'Cantidad', 'Precio']

control_inicio=True
if not lista_de_productos:
    print('lista Vacia')
    n=int(input("quiere cargar productos almacen  digite 1 por si o 0 para salir :"))
    i=0
    while control_inicio == True or n == True:
        
        control_inicio=False
  
        for key in keys:
            value = input(f"Enter {key}: ") 
            producto[key] = value
        lista_de_productos.append(producto)
        i=i+1
        #lista_de_productos.insert(len(lista_de_productos),producto)
        #lista_de_productos[0]['Nombre']='Dan'
        print(lista_de_productos[0]['Nombre'])
        print(lista_de_productos)  
        n=int(input("quiere cargar  mas productos digite 1 por si o 0 para salir :"))
    
     
print(lista_de_productos) 

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutar el código anterior y querer agregar otro diccionario mas a la lista entonces el código   producto[key] = value actualiza las claves del anterior diccionario a los nuevos valores ingresados, con lo cual no logro agregar diccionarios distintos a una lista mediante Input.
Intenté también otros métodos pero siempre me ocurre lo mismo modifico los diccionarios anteriores agregados a la lista.

Como recién comienzo a usar python seguramente estoy cometiendo alguna tragedia teórica de la cual no me doy cuenta

El problema es que no existe "otro diccionario" en cada iteración del ciclo, estás agregando el mismo diccionario a la lista una y otra vez.
Simplificando, lo que haces es equivalente a:
diccionario = {}
lista = []

for n in range(3):
    diccionario[n] = n * n
    lista.append(diccionario)

Creas el diccionario fuera del ciclo y en el ciclo simplemente lo actualizas y lo agregas a la lista repetidamente, pero es el mismo objeto:
>>> diccionario
{'clave': 2}

>>> lista
[{'clave': 2}, {'clave': 2}, {'clave': 2}]

>>> id(lista[0])
130997343544512

>>> id(lista[1])
130997343544512

>>> id(lista[2])
130997343544512

>>> lista[0] is lista[1]
True

El valor es el de la última iteración en "todos" los diccionarios porque no hay un todos, es el mismo objeto agregado tres veces a la lista.
Debes crear un nuevo diccionario en cada iteración del ciclo while, es decir:
    producto = {}  # Crea el diccionario aquí y no antes del ciclo while  
    for key in keys:
        value = input(f"Enter {key}: ") 
        producto[key] = value

Puedes también crear el diccionario por compresión directamente:
lista_de_productos.append({key: input(f"Enter {key}: ") for key in KEYS})

aunque, en este caso, la ventaja de eficiencia que ofrece la compresión de listas/diccionarios carece de importancia al haber un input de por medio. Sin esta justificación, su uso es cuestión de gustos más que nada, para mucha gente es menos legible que crearlo con un for tradicional y a otros les gusta esta sintaxis más...
Dos observaciones:

En Python (y en muchos otros lenguajes), cuando compruebes si algo es cierto o no, en vez de usar el operador de igualdad:
 while control_inicio == True or n == True:

haz simplemente:
while control_inicio or n:

o si quieres saber si es falso simplemente usa not tal como haces en tu if:
while not control_inicio:  # En vez de: while control_inicio == False:


En la primera iteración le preguntas al usuario si quiere agregar un producto, pero aún respondiendo "no" se lo pides de todas formas. Si quieres pedir un producto siempre en la primera iteración, lo lógico sería que eliminaras ese primer input:
KEYS = ('Nombre', 'Cantidad', 'Precio')
lista_de_productos = []

if not lista_de_productos:
    print('Lista de productos vacía')

    n = 1 
    while n:
        producto = {}
        for key in KEYS:
            value = input(f"Enter {key}: ") 
            producto[key] = value
        lista_de_productos.append(producto)

        n = int(input("¿Quiere agregar más productos? Digite 1 por 'si' o 0 para salir: "))

print(lista_de_productos)




Si gracias estaba actualizando producto en cada iteración del while y no creando un nuevo producto muchas gracias !

Si gracias estaba actualizando producto  y todos los productos agregados en cada iteración del while y no creando un nuevo producto para agregarlo.  Al codificar producto ={}  dentro del while lo inicializas ahora si como nuevo y se  puede insertar al final de la lista  al final  como otro producto muchas gracias !
